# MPMoviePlayerController showing black screen with sound in iOS 7, works fine in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios7, mpmovieplayer

//introVideoViewController

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioSession.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
@property(nonatomic,strong) MPMoviePlayerController *playercontroller;
```

What in iOS 7 I can heard my video sound but not the video. It works fine in iOS 6.

```
//introVideoViewController

//prepare & init video
-(void)prepareIntroVideo
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"intro_movie" ofType:@"mp4"]];
    //NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://km.support.apple.com/library/APPLE/APPLECARE_ALLGEOS/HT1211/sample_iTunes.mov"];
    self.playercontroller = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [self.playercontroller.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320,480)];
    self.playercontroller.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
    self.playercontroller.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
    self.playercontroller.fullscreen = YES;
    self.playercontroller.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    //playercontroller.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
    self.playercontroller.view.userInteractionEnabled =NO;
    self.playercontroller.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.playercontroller.shouldAutoplay = NO;
    
    //playercontroller.repeatMode = YES;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:self.playercontroller];
    [self.playercontroller prepareToPlay];
    [self.view addSubview:self.playercontroller.view];
    
    
    // get the handle

    
    // Get the result
    self.firstlaunchVideoCheck = [self.defaults stringForKey:@"firstlaunchVideo"];
    
    //NSLog(@"first launch null or 1 = %@",firstlaunchVideoCheck);
    
    
    if ([self.firstlaunchVideoCheck intValue])
    {
        //skip view overlay
        UIView *skipView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
        UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapping =
        [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showSkipButton)];
        singleTapping.delegate =self;
        singleTapping.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        [skipView addGestureRecognizer:singleTapping];
        
        singleTapping.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
        
        //skipbutton
        self.skipMovieButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        //0, 276, 480, 54)
        
        if (isPhone568)
        {
         [self.skipMovieButton setFrame:CGRectMake(227, 504, 92, 44)];
        }
        else
        {
            [self.skipMovieButton setFrame:CGRectMake(227, 436, 92, 44)];
        }
        
        [self.skipMovieButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        
        UIImage *skipMovieButtonNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button_skip.png"];
        //UIImage *skipMovieButtonPress = [UIImage imageNamed:@"skip-(active).png"];
        
        [self.skipMovieButton setBackgroundImage:skipMovieButtonNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        //[self.skipMovieButton setBackgroundImage:skipMovieButtonPress forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [self.skipMovieButton addTarget:self action:@selector(skipMovie) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [skipView addSubview:self.skipMovieButton];
        [self.view addSubview:skipView];
    }
    [self.playercontroller stop];
    
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.titleImgView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.startMovieButton];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.playercontroller.view];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.skipMovieButton];
}

//play video
-(void)playIntroVideo
{
    NSLog(@"self.playercontroller.playbackState %i",self.playercontroller.playbackState);
    if (self.playercontroller.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying)
    {
        NSLog(@"playerconroller playing, do nothing");
    }
    else if (self.playercontroller.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped)
    {
        NSLog(@"playerconroller playing, do nothing11111111111");
        [self.playercontroller play];
    }
}


//called when video played completed
- (void)moviePlaybackComplete:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    ////NSLog(@"Here Got Called");
    
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:moviePlayerController];
    //[playercontroller.view removeFromSuperview];
    
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                                  object:[UIApplication sharedApplication]];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
                                                  object:[UIApplication sharedApplication]];
    
    
    

    
   if (![self.firstlaunchVideoCheck intValue])
   {
       self.firstlaunchVideoCheck = @"1";
        // get the handle
       [self.defaults setObject:self.firstlaunchVideoCheck forKey:@"firstlaunchVideo"];
       
        // save it
       [self.defaults synchronize];
    }
       
    [self skipMovie];
}
```

Comment: Are you by chance using an iPhone 5S?  I'm having the same issue on a 5S, but it works fine on other devices (even an iPhone 5 running iOS7).  It works fine on iOS 6 too.

Comment: @wermy yes i'm using a 5s.

i fixed it by adding one more line
    self.playercontroller.contentURL = url;

Comment: Dec 2013 .. TIP - it is hugely flakey about file name extensions (files form the net). In my app, .MOV works, .mov crashes the iPhone hard.  Bizarre.  Also the simulator simply doesn't work, it's totally useless and just crashes.  Finally on the MPMoviePlayerViewController approach works, MPMoviePlayerController is useless and broken.

Comment: @ Joe Blow, I have used MPMoviePlayerViewController and presented it but I am still getting black screen while video loading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

all works fine after adding one more line.

```
self.playercontroller.contentURL = url;
```

Comment: Why does it work on the mentioned setups? (iOS 6 and/or iPhone 5)