# MPMovieplayerController show blackscreen when app enter foreground from background

Tags: background, ios7, mpmovieplayercontroller, foreground

I have seen the same question but not have the right solution, so I decided to post my own problem.

I'm using an MPMoviePlayerController for playing video in iOS app. I can make it to play in background within my app or even when user tap on Home button (play in background).

The problem is when MPMoviePlayerController is playing, press home button on iPhone, make the app enter
background. Then tap the app's icon to make the app enter foreground, the MPMoviePlayerController's view will be black screen, audio still continue, only video screen cannot see anything.

This is NOT happen if in background, MPMoviePlayerController play the next video, when come foreground from background it works perfectly. And it also not happen in iOS6 or before.

So in inclusion the problem occurred when play the itself video in iOS7

How to make the MPMoviePlayerController's video shows immediately when app came to foreground?
Many thanks for any help!

Comment: I think this might help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971961/mpmovieplayercontroller-showing-black-screen-with-sound-in-ios-7-works-fine-in

Comment: This is not the solution, anyway thanks [AccBlue](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1598931/accblue)

Comment: Misses code showing how `MPMoviePlayerController` was initialized and also possibly relevant code from the app-delegate. Should get closed!